# Recommended Modem for Israel/Middle East with CM9 for GS II

Tags: cyanogenmod, connection-issues

My connectivity randomly cuts out - and after searching the CM9 discussion threads - I understand my modem is likely incompatible with my region.

I couldn't find a sticky or thread in XDA about recommended modems by geography - so I was hoping to get some advice here from your experience.

I have a Galaxy S II.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you might need to let us know which device you have before anyone can recommend software for it.

Comment: Which model is it? i9100G or the original i9100? Both have very different internals, just be aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

## Identify the Correct Modem

The Galaxy S II modems files usually contain a reference to the zone where they best apply. In your case, the first reference letter should be "J", that appears just after the phone model.

Official Firmware: <sup>July 2012</sup>

> **Middle East**
>
> - United Arab Emirates XSG - I9100JPLPF/I9100OJPLPC/I9100XXLPX ICS 4.0.3
> - Israel Cellcom CEL - I9100TJIKG3/I9100TCELKG3/I9100TJIKG1

You can also find out your modem version by accessing the "About phone" menu option. The value of "baseband" is your modem version.

---

## Modem File

The file [Modem_I9100TJIKI2.7z](http://www.multiupload.nl/8RBZ6LYKS3) should be the most appropriated for your location.

---

## References

- [Samsung Galaxy S2 Firmware Updates via Kies Official Releases compiled list](http://devsrom4android.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/samsung-galaxy-s2-firmware-updates-via.html)
- [Galaxy S 2 Shipped Modem Collection](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1131950)